# Shell scripting:How do I check if a string follows a certain pattern?

Tags: regex, string, shell, comparison

How do I check if a string follows a certain pattern?

For example, I have $var that stores "hello.txt" and the pattern I want to match is "^(.+).txt$" (ie. anything that has "[any text here].txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash builtin =~ you can do this:

```
if [[ "aaaa" =~ a+ ]]
 then
   echo "ok"
 else
  echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: Can I use Shell's in-built '=~'?

Comment: That's completely silly, given that this doesn't call for regex and can be done easily in the portable shell language described by POSIX, without `bash` extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use shell glob patterns:

```
if [[ "$var" == *.txt ]]; then ...

case "$var" in
  *.txt) do something ;;
  *) do something else ;;
esac
```